# Win 8 webview control flashing background color for a split second

Tags: webview

My app has a white background, but the area of a WebView control flashes the background color of the Windows 8 Start screen before the HTML string is loaded into the WebView, and when the user control that is hosting the WebView gets collapsed.  Does anyone know how to fix this, so that my white app doesn't flash blue while I load/hide the WebView?

Note that I have tried setting the background color of the webview to white (via a short html string with the body set to a white background color) as well as setting the height and width of the control to zero, then resizing it to the correct size *AFTER* the html it is supposed to display is passed to the webview control, but the issue still occurs.

I note that there has been a question regarding this here ([Same question from someone on social.msdn.microsoft.com](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/winappswithcsharp/thread/64be28ae-ff0f-4673-b729-9a9a63bd3882)) but that is old and was before windows 8 was officially released.  Just wondering if it was actually resolved?